# Why isn't my updated observable List reflected in the template?

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I've got:

```
my-app
  community-list
```

On attached, my-app gets the user and loads the app.user. In the meantime, community-list is attached (even before app.user is loaded) and so I haven't been able to get the user's starred communities yet. Therefore, the solution I'm working on is as follows.

In community-list.attached():

```
app.changes.listen((List<ChangeRecord> records) {
  if (app.user != null) {
    getUserStarredCommunities();
  }
});
```

Elsewhere in community-list is said metho:

```
  // This is triggered by an app.changes.listen.
  void getUserStarredCommunities() {
    // Determine if this user has starred the community.
    communities.forEach((community) {
      var starredCommunityRef = new db.Firebase(firebaseLocation + '/users/' + app.user.username + '/communities/' + community['id']);
      starredCommunityRef.onValue.listen((e) {
        if (e.snapshot.val() == null) {
          community['userStarred'] = false;
        } else {
          community['userStarred'] = true;
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Note that communities is an observable list in community-list:

```
@observable List communities = toObservable([]);
```

Which is initially populated in community-list.attached():

```
getCommunities() {
    var f = new db.Firebase(firebaseLocation + '/communities');

    var communityRef = f.limit(20);
    communityRef.onChildAdded.listen((e) {
      var community = e.snapshot.val();

      // If no updated date, use the created date.
      if (community['updatedDate'] == null) {
        community['updatedDate'] = DateTime.parse(community['createdDate']);
      }

      // snapshot.name is Firebase's ID, i.e. "the name of the Firebase location"
      // So we'll add that to our local item list.
      community['id'] = e.snapshot.name();

      // Insert each new community into the list.
      communities.add(community);

      // Sort the list by the item's updatedDate, then reverse it.
      communities.sort((m1, m2) => m1["updatedDate"].compareTo(m2["updatedDate"]));
      communities = communities.reversed.toList();
    });
  }
```

In summary, I load the list of communities even before I have a user, but once I have a user I want to update each community (Map) in the list of communities with the userStarred = true/false, which I then use in my community-list template.

1. Alas, it doesn't seem like the List updates. How do I achieve this?
2. This whole app.changes.listen business is expensive. What's the proper practice in a case like this, where an element is loaded before I load objects (like app.user) that will modify it in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)
`toList()` creates a copy of the list. You need to apply `toObservable` again to get an observable list.

```dart
communities = toObservable(communities.reversed.toList());
```

This also assigns a new list to `communities` which is covered by `@observable`.
I think it should trigger anyway

2) You update your communities explicitly. It shouldn't be necessary to listen for `changes`. You can call a method containing

```dart
if (app.user != null) {
  getUserStarredCommunities();
}
```

explicitly each time you change the list.

You also call Firebase for each community when a change in `communities` occurs. I don't know Firebase but it seems you send a request to a server each time which is of course expensive.
You should remember for what `user`+`community` combination you already made the call and use the remembered result instead.

With `app.changes.listen` you listen to any updated of any `@observable` field in your component. If you have other observable fields beside `communities` this method might be called too often.
If you are only interested in changes to `communities` you should put this code into a method like

```dart
communitiesChanged(oldVal, newVal) {
  if (app.user != null) {
    getUserStarredCommunities();
  }
}
```

but the better option is to not listen to changes and another method name and call it explicitly as state above anyways if possible.

Comment: toObservable() did the trick. Super awesome and timely answer! I'll try the other stuff and circle back. Thank you!

Comment: Re: "You can call a method explicitly each time you change the list." the problem is if I have getUserStarredCommunities() in getCommunities(), it'll still have the same result of not having a user the first time it's called. And it won't update once the user *is* loaded because the element's already been attached. If I leave/detach that element and come back, it works, or if I do this app.changes.listen or communitiesChanged trick. I don't understand another way.

Comment: What I suggested should not change the behavior (I can't reason about code that is not contained in your question that might effect the behavior). The only effect should be that `getUserStarredCommunities` might get called less often.
I think the more important thing is to not make redundant calls to `db.Firebase` which is way more expensive than a bit iterating over collections.